# Definite integral of a complex function on a real interval

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

How does 
$$\int\limits_{k_0-(\Delta k/2)}^{k_0+(\Delta k/2)}e^{ikx}dk$$
equal to $(e^{ik_0x}/x)2\sin (\Delta k \cdot x/2)$?

Answer (score 1):

Use the indefinite integrals given in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/177091/19341), to get
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_{k_0-(\Delta k/2)}^{k_0+(\Delta k/2)}e^{ikx}dk
&=& \frac{1}{i x} e^{ikx}\Biggr|_{k_0-(\Delta k/2)}^{k_0+(\Delta k/2)}\\
&=& \frac{1}{i x} e^{i(k_0+(\Delta k/2))x} -\frac{1}{i x} e^{i(k_0-(\Delta k/2))x}\\
&=& \frac{e^{ik_0x}}{i x} \left(e^{i((\Delta k/2))x} -e^{i(-(\Delta k/2))x}\right)\\
&=& \frac{e^{ik_0x}}{x} 2\sin(x\Delta k/2).
\end{eqnarray}
$$
And to come back to your first question: Let $k_0=0$, $\Delta k/2=\frac1a$, forget the $2$ and look at
$$
\lim_{a\to 0 } \frac{1/a}{x/a} \sin(x/a)=\lim_{a\to 0 } \frac{1}{a} \text{sinc}(x/a)=\delta(x),
$$
yet another representation of [Dirac's $\delta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function#Relationship_to_the_Dirac_delta_distribution).