# How does the Fourier Transform work??

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I was trying to understand how the Fourier Transform works and wanted to test it on $\cos(Ax)$.
I know that the FT for $\cos(Ax)$ is $\delta(A)$ and $\delta(-A)$. So I wanted to check if for other values of $\omega$ if the FT is zeros. (Please note, I'm still ramping up on creating the math equation. I apologize if something is improper)

The FT of $\cos(x)$ (so $A = 1$) is:
$$
F(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(x)e^{-jwt} dt 
$$
This implies, I'll have a $\delta(x)$ at $x=1$ and $-1$. For all other cases, it should be 0.
$$
$$
Hence, at $\omega = 10$ (10 times the frequency of the original), the FT should be zero...

\begin{align}
F(10) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{(e^{jt}+e^{-jt})e^{-10jt} dt}\\
&= {\frac{1}{2}(e^{-9jt})|_{-\infty}^{\infty}+ \frac{1}{2}(e^{-11jt})|_{-\infty}^{\infty}}\end{align}

But I'm stuck here and it looks like the answer is non-zero. From [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177091/int-infty-infty-eikxdx-equals-what?newreg=c5451d4aa50f436785155fa20625366c), I'm getting a non-zero result. Could someone please help in solving this integral? Also, please correct me if my assumption is totally wrong.

Comment: For $\infty$ use `\infty`.

Comment: To define the Fourier transform of $\cos$, which is not in $L^1(\mathbb R)$, one has to use [distribution theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)).

Comment: @K.defaoite will do.
@ md2perpe, the link was enough for me to give up on this apparent rabbit hole immediately. Any page which concentrates on the cosine directly?

Comment: Delta function makes sense as an integral with other functions. This is its meaning - to "cut out" one point in a smooth function when integrating the product of a delta function and a smooth function. If you are trying to get an "explicit" delta function - it can be a function that does not necessarily equal zero at other points. For example, it can be a highly oscillating function - like the expressions you got. Integral from these strongly oscillating functions with a smooth function will give zero over any interval not including the singularity point (i.e., the zero point in your case).